# Struts2 not worked with annotated action

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, annotations, struts2-convention-plugin

I just start to learn some Struts2 and try to create simple web page. I made a `Action` class, add some annotation, them I made some JSP and set filter in `web.xml` file, but when I try to get page I just see work of JSP not any Struts2.

**ClientListAction.java:**

```
@Namespace("/")
@ResultPath(value = "/")
@Result(name = "success", location = "pages/clientList.jsp")
public class ClientListAction extends ActionSupport {

    private String username = "TEST";

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

**clientList.jsp:**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test page Struts 2</title>
</head>
<body>
<h4>Hello <s:property value="username"/></h4>
</body>
</html>
```

**web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">

    <display-name>Clients Application</display-name>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**URL:**

```
http://localhost:8080/pages/clientList.jsp
```

**Result:**

```
Hello
```

Comment: URL is wrong. You are accessing the jsp directly. You should access the action.
Your url should be something like : `localhost:8080\myapp\clientListAction`

Comment: I tried but it isn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `@ResultPath(value = "/")` and set the absolute path for `location` attribute. Also in the result annotation `name = "success"` is used by default, writing it isn't necessary. To use annotation configuration required to add struts2-convention plugin to the module dependencies. To execute action you need to enter url

```
http://localhost:8080/client-list
```

if your module is deployed to the root context, or add context path before the action name.